# Add Woocommerce addon price to the Posts by using Advanced custom fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Currently I am using wordpress theme Listgo(https://listgo.wiloke.com). I have modified the theme completely. i have linked the woocommerce product with the listing using the id of listing and product, when ever user is creating a listing, a new product is also created automatically with that listing,
in listing page, the product price is showing in side bar, by this hook $_product->get_price();
My question is: how can I place the woocommerce Extra price fields in the listing(http://liveclass.xyz/listing/online-mock-interview-cybersecurity-specialist-ey/).
Secondly I have made the Extra price addons, for listing page(http://liveclass.xyz/listing/online-mock-interview-with-hr-business-partner-at-amazon/)by using advanced custom fields, but the addon price is not updating in the checkout page.

Help will be highly appreciated.